# How to use Ansible modules replace or inline instead shell command with SED

Tags: search, sed, replace, ansible

i have file with string:

```
MYAPP.db.username.DEV=MYUSERNAME
```

Where:

```
MYAPP mean name of applications
DEV means environment
MYUSERNAME means name of user for connection to db
```

I need to replace these variables according to variables, that i have in some script.
I am using this:

```
- name: Replace line
  shell: sed -i "/{{ name_of_app }}.db.username.{{ name_of_environment }}/c\\{{ name_of_app }}.db.username.{{ name_of_environment }}={{ name_of_user_to_db }}" /path/to/my/apps/{{ name_of_app }}/config/{{ name_of_app }}.config
```

It works fine, but i see warnings in output of ansible

```
 [WARNING]: Consider using the replace, lineinfile or template module rather
than running sed.  If you need to use command because replace, lineinfile or
template is insufficient you can add warn=False to this command task or set
command_warnings=False in ansible.cfg to get rid of this message.
changed:
```

I have tried this

```
- name: Replace line via replace method
  replace: 
    dest: "/path/to/my/apps/{{ name_of_app }}/config/{{ name_of_app }}.config"
    regexp: "{{ name_of_app }}.db.username.{{ name_of_environment }}"
    replace: "{{ name_of_app }}.db.username.{{ name_of_environment }}={{ name_of_user_to_db }}"
```

and this

```
- name: Replace line via lineinfile method
  lineinfile: 
    dest: "/path/to/my/apps/{{ name_of_app }}/config/{{ name_of_app }}.config"
    regexp: "{{ name_of_app }}.db.username.{{ name_of_environment }}"
    line: "{{ name_of_app }}.db.username.{{ name_of_environment }}={{ name_of_user_to_db }}"
    backrefs: yes
```

each time, i have result with failed:

```
FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (replace) module: when Supported parameters include: after, attributes, backup, before, content, delimiter, directory_mode, encoding, follow, force, group, mode, owner, path, regexp, remote_src, replace, selevel, serole, setype, seuser, src, unsafe_writes, validate"}
```

Can you help me, where i have error in my playbook ?

Answer (score 0):

> FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (replace) module: when"}

In the future, post the **real** playbook or task that you are running, without editoralizing, since it would otherwise be impossible for people to help you without seeing what you are really running

As is clearly stated in the error message, the `replace:` task does not accept a `when:` parameter. You are in that situation because you have mis-indented your `when:` statement

```
# you have, which is _incorrect_
- replace:
    dest: "/path/to/my/apps/{{ name_of_app }}/config/{{ name_of_app }}.config"
    when: 1 == 1
```

but it should be:

```
- replace:
    dest: "/path/to/my/apps/{{ name_of_app }}/config/{{ name_of_app }}.config"
  when: 1 == 1
```